# Better subclass UIElements or create Category to customize

Tags: ios, objective-c, subclass, objective-c-category

I want to customize many UIElements easily, so I have read that I can do it by Category the UILabel, ex. UILabel+Custom, or subclassing the UIElement. I just want to know when is better to use Category and when is better Subclassing. Or maybe one of those is the best.

Comment: There is no good answer as asked. As usual, it depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I would like to see some example of different cases. I do not know in what cases I should use one or the other, I mean, I do not know when it depends in one thing and when in other..

Answer (score 1):

As @rmaddy mentioned in a comment, it depends what sorts of things you are trying to do. I'll try to cover a few cases for you to answer your question.

## Subclassing — should be used when you need to...

- override an object's methods
- defining a more specific object (e.g. a `Truck` should subclass the more generic object `Car`)

## Categories — should be used when you need to...

- provide additional functionality for all types of the generic class
- access methods in a system class or change an existing method's functionality where the class you don't directly instantiate that system object (NOTE: should be used only in rare cases)

If there are any other suggestions for when to use subclassing versus categories, feel free to add them in the comments.

@RoxeeMan, does this seem to answer your question?

Comment: Is good your answer but I was thinking more in UIElements,something more specific